# My file isn't rendering and attempting to do so sometimes crashes PC (memory-related?)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, memory-management

I am trying to render a still frame of a complex scene. When I render I often watch the tiling render the scene over that default checkerboard pattern, and it usually finishes the whole image. However, after tiling the whole image, it will disappear and I'm left with the checkerboard pattern again. I have tried reducing the tiling size a ton, using the simplify settings to minimize subdivisions, and even reduced the sampling a ton, however the scene is continuing to give me grief. I have tried rendering at different sized and file types, but still no luck. I have gotten the "out of memory" error message here and there, and sometimes the rendering even crashes my whole PC and it restarts.

I am working with a geforce gtx 1070, which I believe has about 8GB VRAM. Additionally, I have 48GB RAM and an intel I5. At this point I have no idea what to try. Thank you.

Comment: Have you made any changes in the compositing tab? Any chance the Compositor output got disconnected?

Comment: Unfortunately I’ve never done anything there so it couldn’t be that.

Comment: how many texturs to you have and how larg are they? .. they take up memory as well .. actualy lots

Comment: No textures, just materials! And there are around 10 at the moment!